# jQuery drop down menu not working properly

Tags: jquery, menu

I am quite new to website designing and i have been trying to solve this solution since last few hours but couldnt  find any solution. I am trying to make a drop down menu. here is the html codes..

```
<ul class="mainnav">
        <li><a href="#" class="navText"> <span class="navText"> Home </span> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navText"><span class="navText"> Games </span></a>
            <ul>
                <li> Battlefield 3</li>
                <li> Call Of Duty </li>
                <li> Assiaisn's creed </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navText"> <span class="navText"> Servers </span> </a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="navText"> <span class="navText"> Coming Soon </span> </a></li>

</ul>
```

and css is like...

```
ul.mainnav{
    background:#f9f9f9;
    font-size:25px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:200px;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;

}

ul.mainnav > li{
    background:#f9f9f9;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul.mainnav > li a{
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#333333;
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;  
    top:0px;
    margin:0;   
    overflow:hidden
}
ul.mainnav > li a span.navText{
    height:50px;
    padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
    display:block;
    /*outline:1px dashed blue; */
}
ul.mainnav > li a span.hiddenText{  
    display:block;
    line-height:50px;
    height:50px;
    color: red;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px;
    /* outline:1px dashed green; */
}

ul.mainnav > li  ul{
    width:200px;
    background:#CCCCCC;
    font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
    font-size:18px;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul.mainnav > li  ul li{
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    display:block;
    clear:left;
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    margin:0;
}
```

and js is like..

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

$( "span.navText" ).each(function(color) {
        var text = $(this).text()
        $(this).append('<br><span class="hiddenText">'+text+'</span>')
    });


$('ul.mainnav li a').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).stop().children('span.navText').stop().animate({
                marginTop: '-50',
            }, 250)

        },
        function(){
            $(this).stop().children('span.navText').stop().animate({
                marginTop: '0',
            }, 250)
        }

    )
});
```

Now the problem is sub-menu is not positioned correctly. You can see this here...
http://jsfiddle.net/yMUUN/

I want to remove that small gap between main menu and sub menu.

It would be very helpful for me if you can help me in solving this problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, I like that gap. You can set opacity 0 on submenu, and on hover set opacity 1. That will cause nice effect :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a line-height to the following class fixes the gap:

```
ul.mainnav > li{
    background:#f9f9f9;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
        line-height: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @kenneth now its ok.. thanks a lot man.. can u tell where i was making mistake?

Comment: I don't know, maybe you made a mistake copying the code. Anyway, happy to help. Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.